# Mint settings panel not showing up

Tags: linux-mint, settings

Today I turn on my computer, Mint 
I want to turn on my second monitor in the settings but system settings are not showing up.

-> I click the menu icon, I type system then click system settings that just showed up in the bar, then nothing happens

I tried what is suggested here : 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/575548/system-settings-stopped-showing-up

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

+reboot

This didn't do anything.

I guess a solution would be to uninstall system settings and reinstall it but I have no idea which package it can be.